# Combine all values of a map where each value is a dataframe

Tags: scala, dataframe, scala-collections

In Scala using Spark, I have a Map where the key is a String, and the value is a DataFrame.

Schema looks like this:

```
scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame] = Map(Key_A -> [value_col1: string, value_col2: string ... 1 more field], Key_B -> [value_col1: string, value_col2: string ... 1 more field])
```

I do not care about the keys here. I want a dataframe that combines all the values and would look like this.

```
value_col1     value_col2
    1               2
    1.1             2.2
```

I am looking to see how to do this using simple as well as recommended/efficient approaches.

Comment: Hi there, so you are actually to populate the schema from the Map or it will contain the data as well?

Comment: Each key is a string.
Each value is a dataframe.

The dataframe contains the data. For example:
`value_col1     value_col2
    1               2`

Similarly, for key 2, the dataframe may look like:
`value_col1     value_col2
    1.1               2.2`

I'd like to combine this data.

Comment: All the dataframes have the same schema?

Comment: Yes all dataframes have same schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use map to iterate among the map values and merge the dataframes. If your schema remains identical for all the dataframes you can use a `union` to merge the data:

```scala
val mapping = Map("df1" -> df1, "df2" -> df)

val finalDF = mapping.values.map{df =>
  df.select("*")
}.reduce((d0, d1) => d0.union(d1))
```

Otherwise, if the dataframes have different schema then replace the `union` with an `inner join`:

```scala
val finalDF = mapping.values.map{df =>
  df.select("*")
}.reduce((d0, d1) => d0.join(d1, "id"))
```

Here we assume that the dataframes share the same `id` field.